# how many partition is suitable per each node in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, partition

I'm testing cassandra.
before setting my cassandra nodes at server.

**I wonder how many partitions are suitable per each node .**

- i'm planning to save 0~18000000 data per each partition.
- Q: partitions?????? / 1node ==> stable

```
    CREATE TABLE if not exists  access_log
 (  time_boundary int, --yyyymmddhh
    user_id TEXT,  --user01
    timestamp bigint, --yyyymmddhhmmssms
    url TEXT, -- /file/file/blabla~~
    menu_id TEXT, 
    ip TEXT,
    params map, -- 
    PRIMARY KEY((time_boundary),user_id,timestamp)
 ) ;
```

Comment: and i'm planning to create 25000 partitions per 1 node

Comment: please show your table schema, and other information

Comment: i added my table schema for sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider a safe rule of thumb (depends heavily on schema and write rates) to be about 1-4 billion partitions within a table (per node) you start to get issues with repair over streaming with the `2^20` max merkle tree depth.

With incremental repair you can go higher (only recommended on latest 3.11.x, and even there test heavily), providing you are using LeveledCompactionStrategy. With SizeTieredCompactionStrategy `ALTER TABLE yourtable WITH min_index_interval = 4096 and max_index_interval = 4096` (or higher if you see issues) to prevent an OOM when the compactions preallocate the index summaries.